# Azure Function App Execution count and IoT Hub triggers

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I am using Consumption Plan Function App.

I have IoT Devices which are communicating with the IoT Hub. The IoT Hub triggers an Azure Function from my Function App.

The image below was obtained from the Azure Function App setting, and it shows the IoT Hub-triggered function has an execution count of over 250.

Does this mean that there are 250 instances of Azure Function App?  Normal?

If was to introduce batch processing for IoT Hub messages, what would be classified as batch of messages? Do they need to have a timestamp within a certain limit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Consumption Plan Function App won't scale over 200 instances (100 for Linux), that's a hard limit. You can use the Function's metrics to check the amount of instances running. Select a metric and split it by 'instance'

[image: Screenshot of Metrics configuration]

Edit with info from comments:

It's possible that you're handling all those requests from 1 instance. The Function will scale out automatically. How that works is described [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#event-hubs-trigger); however, no exact logic for scaling is described. it's not a hard link to the number of messages available on the Event Hub.

Comment: So is Function Execution Count reflecting how many times a trigger has invoked a function from my Function App, or how the QTY of Function App instances?  If I am correct, on a Function App Consumption plan, the max instances are 200, but based on the plots I am seeing, my App peak at about 350, so maybe this is not the same thing?

Comment: The Function Execution Count measures how often a Function is triggered. This could be multiple executions of the same instance, or executions on multiple instances. By splitting the result by instance (right side of the screenshot) you should get an overview of how many instances were running and how many executions they did, each.

Comment: Ok, I can see there is a multiple instance, but maybe I am wrong, they do not overlap each other but as one instance closes, anther starts or at least from the plots I am seeing. 

Can you have multiple instance running at the same time?

Comment: Secondly, how many function execution results in a new instance?

Comment: It's entirely possible that you are only running 1 instance that's handling all messages. There is no set number of executions that results in a new instance. The way it works is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#event-hubs-trigger). But that page won't give you the exact logic they use to scale.

Comment: Thank I will read that. Few months ago i did get some error message saying my CPU usage was over 80%, I was wondering why no instance was created as CPU usage increased?